# 空睨んでも - how can I tell when sora is being used for something other than the sky

Tags: conjugations, grammar, poetry

I like to translate K-pop and anime themes as a hobby to help me understand and memorize the language. In Gurenge, a certain line sticks out: 夜の匂いに　空睨んでも.
My research suggests that if Sora comes before an adjective or verb, then it could mean "fake". Is that the case here, or does Sora not have its own grammar particle (に), because it would be repeating the exact same syllable?

Comment: Without any further context, I would say that 夜 is a clue that 空 here refers to the sky.

Comment: That's all the context given from the song.

Answer (score 1):

I think that 空 means "sky" here and that the sentence means:

> even if I look up the sky in the scent of the night